# generate an image from pythob code and add it in a binary field odoo

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-11

I am currently in odoo 11 I am developing a custom module I have created a button that performs the rendering of a wizard view, in that wizard view there is a binary field .... I want that when I click the button I generate an image or a txt and assign it to the binary field allowing me to download the txt or the image below I will show you the following example:

This is the button that I created:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgt5t.png)

When giving clik muentra the following:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lkyX.png)

Well, the problem is the following:

When I create my binary field in my model:

```
class RegisterBulk (models.Model):
    _name = 'stock.order.package'
    n_bulk = fields.Integer(string = 'n° Nulto')
    n_order = fields.Char(string = 'n° Pedido')
    weight = fields.Float(string = 'Peso' , required = True)
    context_products = fields.Many2many('stock.table.products',string = 'Productos')
    bar_bulk = fields.Char(string = 'Codigo del Bulto')
    file = fields.Binary('Etiqueta' ,readonly = True)
```

which is called file, and in my xml I think it in the following way:

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
       <field name="file" filename="sale_order_data" />
</div>
```

I want that when opening the wizard the file is loaded to be able to download it, I am trying to do this in the method of my created button:

```
        pdf_file = open('data.txt', 'w+')
        if pdf_file:
            print "paso"
            salida = 'PRuebaaaaaaaaaa'
            pdf_file.write(salida)



        return {
            'name': ('Regsitro de Bulto'),
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode': 'form',
            'res_model': 'stock.order.package',
            'view_id': False,
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'target': 'new',
            'context': {
                'default_n_order': self.name,
                'default_n_bulk': t_bulk ,
                'default_context_products': products,
                'default_bar_bulk': code,
                'default_file': base64.encodestring(pdf_file),


            },
        }
```

but when I hit the button I get this error:

```
  File "c:\python27\Lib\base64.py", line 320, in encodestring
    for i in range(0, len(s), MAXBINSIZE):
TypeError: object of type 'file' has no len()
```

finally for now I'm just trying to pass a txt ideal would be an image that I'll create with the library pillow and zpl, but to have an idea I'm doing with the txt but I get the error mentioned above.